# Stop EF Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have threeType MaliOp, LoanEBD, PrmEBD

```
    public class MaliOp
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int OldId { get; set; }

        public byte MaliTable { get; set; }

        public string Date { get; set; }

        public short OpState { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoanEBD : MaliOp
    {
        public int? BId { get; set; }
        public int? Loan { get; set; }
        public int? PayerBimeGozar { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int OldId { get; set; }
    }

    public class PrmEBD : MaliOp
    {
        public int? PayerBimeGozar { get; set; }
        public int? BId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int OldId { get; set; }
    }
```

the two Entity PrmEBD and LoanEBD Inherit from MaliOp. I want create DBContext in Entity Framework by by using this three types.
I have three Table in Database fro each one of them.
I don't want to use any EF Inhertance Strategy and add each one as Independent Types. but can't and EF Use either one of Inhertance strategy.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create a IMaliOp Interface and let MaliOp implement it.
2. let the two classes implement the IMaliOp interface as well
3. Then use automapper (or something similar) to automatically transfer the information from the Entity object to your regular object.

This two classes would represent DTO (data transfer object). there are many strategies, out there for DTO-s

You should avoid having Classes inherit Entities, otherwise you applications classes will get too tightly coupled, and changes might prove them self to become too painful

Answer (score 0):

In your context, override OnModelCreating;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PrmEBD>().ToTable("PrmEBDs");
    modelBuilder.Entity<LoanEBD>().ToTable("LoanEBD");
    modelBuilder.Entity<MaliOp>().ToTable("MaliOp");
}
```

This will create three separate tables in your database.

You will need to make sure that when you do a query over MaliOp, that you don't pull in instances from all three tables. You may want to go wit the approach of creating a common `interface` for all three, so that they don't actually inherit from each other, too